# how to create JavaScript object using a for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, for-loop, each

i have an object sample `data`:

```
[Object, Object, Object]
  0: Object
    test_id: "1"
    area: "high"
  1: Object
    test_id: "1"
    area: "saw"
  2: Object
    test_id: "2"
    area: "look"
```

i am trying to create a new object by grouping by `test_id`.

```
var obj = new Object();
$.each(data, function(k, v){
    obj[v.test_id] += {area: v.area};
});
```

this doesn't seem to work, it returns only one object line...

i am trying to get something like:

```
1: {
    {area: "high"}
    {area: "saw"}
}
2: {
    {area: "look""
}
```

any ideas? thanks

Comment: Man, you are doing some crazy stuff within those few code lines! :)

Comment: @JohnDoe There is a always a way to complicate things :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your edit I notice something, you're trying to create a javascript object with a property with no name, this is not the format. In JSON (javascript object notation) each property must have a value, what you are trying to store better fits an array.

Instead, push it into an array

```
    $.each(data, function(k, v){
    obj[v.test_id].area.push(v.area);
});
```

just remember to create obj[v.test_id] first and to set its area property to [].
This results in:

```
1: {
    area: ["high","saw"]
}
3: {
    area: ["look"]
}
```

Also, if you're willing to consider using underscore it has very powerful (yet basic) collection methods, you might want to have a look at http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy

Comment: i edited. i meant those to be objects as well... but i guess i can always convert your array back into object

Comment: Javascript objects are key value pairs, there is not much sense in code like {1: {{area: "high"},{area: "high"}}} , however, arrays make more sense and you can use {1: [{area: "high"},{area: "high"}}], this would be an object with a property called "1" that contains array of objects, each having an area property